# Update dictionary value when key exists in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Variations of this question have been asked a lot, but I can't find an answer that addresses my query:

My list `path_coords` contains tuples which match keys in my dictionary `grid` I'm tring to change the value of each item in `grid` to 'X' if the key is present in `path_coords`

Example here works, as `path_coords` is a single tuple

```
# Define grid dimensions
width = 4
height = 4

# Grid dictionary
grid = {(0,0): "Y", (0,1): "Y", (0,2): "Y", (0,3): "Y",
        (1,0): "Y", (1,1): "Y", (1,2): "Y", (1,3): "Y",
        (2,0): "Y", (2,1): "Y", (2,2): "Y", (2,3): "Y",
        (3,0): "Y", (3,1): "Y", (3,2): "Y", (3,3): "Y"}

# Dictionary values to change
path_coords = (1,1)
grid[path_coords] = 'X'

# Create grid
for y in range(height):
    row = [grid[(y,x)] for x in range(width)]
    print(*row)
```

But this doesn't work, as the tuples are in a list?

```
# Define grid dimensions
width = 4
height = 4

# Grid dictionary
grid = {(0,0): "Y", (0,1): "Y", (0,2): "Y", (0,3): "Y",
        (1,0): "Y", (1,1): "Y", (1,2): "Y", (1,3): "Y",
        (2,0): "Y", (2,1): "Y", (2,2): "Y", (2,3): "Y",
        (3,0): "Y", (3,1): "Y", (3,2): "Y", (3,3): "Y"}

# Dictionary values to change
path_coords = [(1,1), (2,2)]
grid[path_coords] = 'X'

# Create grid
for y in range(height):
    row = [grid[(y,x)] for x in range(width)]
    print(*row)
```

I've tried a for loop, but get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
for path in path_coords:
    grid[path_coords] = 'X'
```

Comment: Loop over the list, doing what you did before for each item in it.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks & sorry I just added a bit in an edit above - I've tried a to loop over the list but it throws a typeerror, I presume I'm making a stupid error with the loop?

Comment: What is the point of defining `path` if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for this, it's been a long day & I'm not thinking... All sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are aiming for?

```
width = 4
height = 4

# Grid dictionary
grid = {(0,0): "Y", (0,1): "Y", (0,2): "Y", (0,3): "Y",
        (1,0): "Y", (1,1): "Y", (1,2): "Y", (1,3): "Y",
        (2,0): "Y", (2,1): "Y", (2,2): "Y", (2,3): "Y",
        (3,0): "Y", (3,1): "Y", (3,2): "Y", (3,3): "Y"}

# Dictionary values to change
path_coords = [(1,1),(2,2)]
for coord in path_coords:
    grid[coord] = 'X'

# Create grid
for y in range(height):
    row = [grid[(y,x)] for x in range(width)]
    print(*row)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I obviously wasn't thinking properly with this one.

Comment: Sometimes its helpful to get a second pair of eyes on code